# How to reset a session in R?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Consider the example below

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyUI(
  tabPanel("VIEW",
           tabsetPanel(id="viewic",
                       tabPanel("view1",
                                fluidRow( column(2,
                                                 actionButton("button1", "BUTTON1")),
                                          column(2,
                                                 actionButton("button2", "BUTTON2"))
                                ))
                       tabPanel(" View2"))),
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("ui1")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("ui2")
  ))
```

Server:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyServer(function(input, output,session){

  observeEvent(
    input$button1, 
    output$ui1 <- renderUI({isolate({
      column(3, 
             selectInput("selectview1", 
                         label = "Select Id", 
                         choices = c("1","2","3")
             ))})}))

  observeEvent(
    input$button2, 
    output$ui2 <- renderUI({isolate({
      column(3, 
             selectInput("selectview2", 
                         label = "Select Id", 
                         choices = c("4","5","6")
             ))})}))

})
```

How to reset the session,ie; when I press button1 the selectinput with id selectview1 appears and when I press the button2 the selectInput with id selectview2 defined inside it appears but the selectinput that appeared firstly when the button1  was clicked is also being displayed along with it  and vice versa.I tried reset and toggle but it didn't worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: use conditionalPanel on your selectInputs. So something to the effect of:

`conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.button1 % 2 > 0',
   uiOutput("ui1")
)`

This checks whether or not the value of your actionButton is even and only displays it when it is odd. So assuming the button starts at a 0 value, it will display after 1, 3, 5, 7... clicks.

I think this should work. Can you try it out?

---

If you just want to hide a button depending on a click, look into conditionalPanel() and wrap your button code (ui side) in that function.

http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html

Comment: Thank you Sir, I don't want to hide the button but the output obtained by clicking one button  when the another button is clicked.

Comment: Sir but the button1 can be clicked after clicking button2 first,it depends on the user.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your initial question then. Can you clarify? The conditionalPanel can be set for both ui1 and ui2 separately, so button order shouldn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

ui.R

library(shiny)

library(shinyjs)

shinyUI(

fluidPage(

tabPanel("VIEW",

```
       tabsetPanel(id="viewic",

                   tabPanel("view1",
```

fluidRow( column(2,

```
                                             actionButton("button1", "BUTTON1")),
```

column(2,

```
                                    actionButton("button2", "BUTTON2"))

 )),
```

tabPanel(" View2"))),

fluidRow(

```
uiOutput("ui1")
```

),

fluidRow(

```
uiOutput("ui2")
```

)))

server.R

library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyServer(function(input, output,session){

observeEvent(

```
input$button1, 

output$ui1 <- renderUI({isolate({


  output$ui2<-renderUI(

    isolate({

      dataTableOutput(NULL)  


    } ) )
  column(3, 

         selectInput("selectview1", 

                     label = "Select Id", 

                     choices = c("1","2","3")
         ))})}))
```

observeEvent(

```
input$button2, 

output$ui2 <- renderUI({isolate({

  output$ui1<-renderUI(

    isolate({

      dataTableOutput(NULL)  


    } ) )
```

column(3,

```
         selectInput("selectview2", 

                     label = "Select Id", 

                     choices = c("4","5","6")

         ))})}))
```

})

This code  worked.

Comment: As it is this answer is not readable. Please reformat it for people to make most of it.